Compare BPF maps in fentry/htab_map_update_elem hook
I'd like to perform actions after a value is inserted to the specific map, using fentry/htab_map_update_elem hook. How can I check if struct bpf_map* map is the map that declared in BPF code?
For example,
// kernel BPF program

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __uint(max_entries, 128);
    __type(key, __u32);
    __type(value, __u32);
} mymap SEC(".maps");

SEC("fentry/htab_map_update_elem")
int mymap_prog(struct bpf_map* map, void* key, void* value, u64 map_flags) {
    // Here, how to check if map == mymap?
}

// user program
int main() {
    struct mymap_bpf* skel;
    skel = ...

    // Update mymap and trigger map update hook
    bpf_map__update_elem(skel->maps.mymap, ...);

(Skeleton header file is generated with bpftool)
Thank you in advance.

TL;DR. You can identify the map by checking its ID, with map->id and bpf_map_get_info_by_fd.

On the BPF side:
SEC("fentry/htab_map_update_elem")
int mymap_prog(struct bpf_map* map, void* key, void* value, u64 map_flags) {
    if (map->id == MY_MAP_ID)
        ...
}

On the libbpf side:
struct bpf_map_info info_m = {};

ret = bpf_map_get_info_by_fd(bpf_map__fd(skel->maps.mymap),
                             &info_m, sizeof(info_m));

// The map ID is at info_m.id.

Then you can either pass info_m.id to the BPF program via a map or you can hardcode it as MY_MAP_ID as I did above.

Thank you for your answer! By the way, what does hardcoding map id mean? Can map id be manually specified in declaration? Or do you mean to set MY_MAP_ID variable with the map id got from bpf_map_get_info_by_fd(...); info_m.id?

Yes, by hardcoding I meant that you could rewrite the source C file of the BPF program to replace MY_MAP_ID with the actual value retrieved by libbpf.
